# Pure Pipes in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

As a beginner in Angular, I came across the pure pipes which

- a)   Executes only when a pure change to the input value is detected.
- b)   A pure change is either a change to a primitive input value
  (String, Number, Boolean) or a changed object reference (Array, Date,
  Function, Object).
- c)   A Pure pipe is not executed if the input to the pipe is an
  object and only the property values of that object changes but not
  the reference.

The object reference part I am clear with and the problem lies with the primitive types.

A crucial fact lies on optimization with pure pipe is

***Angular is going to evaluate given pure pipe call only if it has received different arguments compared to its previous invocation.***

I tried with an example:

**applypure.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'applypure',
  pure: true 
})
export class ApplypurePipe implements PipeTransform {
  count = 0;
  constructor() {
    // To determine an instance is created
    console.log('pipe created:');
  }

    transform(value: number, exponent: number): number {
    //this.count++;
    console.log(value);
    return Math.pow(value, exponent);;
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
            {{12 | applypure : 2}}
            {{12 | applypure: 2 }}  
           `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  }     
}
```

The result is shown below :

[image: Result]

**The same input is being passed to pure pipe immediately after, yet its transform method is called twice. Shouldn't it skip the re-evaluation?. Please clarify.**

Comment: The state `pure` is per pipe. It relates to the passed in value and is not reused if you use that pipe multiple times. It says so in point `a)`.

Comment: @Silvermind; Could you please elaborate a bit (an example)?

Comment: @jason if you look at the log pipe is created only once and the same is reused when the pipe is dealing with the same input, transform will called based on the pipe usage

Comment: @Vishnu: Creation of a pipe instance and execution are different IMO.

Comment: @Jason, pure pipe remembers last input for change detection purpose.

Comment: @ABOS: how it's linked with re-evaluation on the same input ?

Comment: @Jason, you are either viewing them as a single pipe instance or some results are cached in the pipe.

Comment: stop using angular it's cancer

Answer (score 1):

There is no shared "cache" between pipes. The "caching" applies for every call in the template

Comment: it's only one pipe and a single instance is created.

Comment: You actually create an instance every time you call it in your template

Comment: but log doesn't says so!

Comment: You're right, as the pipe is stateless, it doesn't make sense to create one instance per template call. I edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the right ***expression*** !.

a) to make sharing/caching work I believe there should be ***only one pipe usage*** of the expression in the component. The transform function of the pure pipe wont re-evaluate for the ***immediate same input***.

Eg. When you input 12 and enter, transform fn is invoked and if you immediately input 12 again the invocation of transform fn is skipped.

***So in Pure Pipes, last Input to the piped expression will be checked and it's the criteria for a valid change detection to run when compared to immediate next inputs.***

**app.component.html**

```
    Type:
<input type="text" #box (keyup.enter)="addName(box.value); box.value=''" placeholder="Parameter"> 
  <div *ngIf="number2">
  {{number2 | applypure : 2}} 
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent  {
  number2: number;

  addName(num: number) {
    this.number2 = num;
    console.log("Log at component: "+ this.number2);
  }

}
```

After First Input of 12
[image: After first Input of 12]

After second Input of 12
[image: After second Input of 12]

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is happening because every time you use your pipe in the HTML it makes a call to the transform function. The pipe doesn't differ between the attributes you are passing to its function, according to the [PipeTransform](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.7/packages/core/src/change_detection/pipe_transform.ts) interface in the Angular repository:

> Angular invokes the `transform` method with the value of a binding
>    as the first argument, and any parameters as the second argument in list form.